Бесконечная загрузка фонового видео в firefox
Использую фоновое видео на странице авторизации. Так же использую Pace - плагин load progress bar https://codebyzach.github.io/pace/. В браузерах edge, chrome, yandex работает все корректно. Но в FireFox плагин показывает загрузку непрерывно, но видео при этом работает. Видео .mp4  24532 KБ.
<video preload="auto" autoplay loop muted class="full-screen_video" id="myVideo">
    <source src="/public/nightRoadLowQ.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>




Вот тут он решил проблему - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78028991/pace-js-takes-longer-to-load-on-firefox

@ЕвгенийЛи Спасибо. Я даже и не подумал бы что проблема с плагином. Просто на всякий случай его упомянул)
